# Not able to Install Flutter To macOS Big Sur with Apple M1 Chip

Tags: macos, flutter, flutter-dependencies, macos-big-sur

SOS!!!!!

I have tried to install flutter on my new mac mini having below confugaration,
[image]

Having below folder structure,
[image]

Also have set below paths,
[image]

Always showing below error,

[image]

Following https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Any help on this?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I had a different problem, but maybe it will be helpful for you as well.
1. Open up System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Click on the lock to unlock the settings. 
2. Run the flutter doctor in the terminal
3. Did anything popup in the Security & Privacy window that you might need to allow?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download android studio to install all android related (sdk, emulator).
(Add plugins flutter and dart to android studio when installed)
Then install flutter (git clone).
Then install xcode.

It will work.